# how to remove variable length sub string

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite database and I have a  column with data type text and the data of this column is like "abc 5.1.5.6 abc" and I want to remove all digits ?

Answer (score 0):

You could call [replace](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) ten times, once for each possible digit:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = replace(replace(replace(
                replace(replace(replace(
                 replace(replace(replace(
                  replace(MyColumn, '0', ''),
                 '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''),
                '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''),
               '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', '')
```